# python range() in for loop maximum

Tags: python, loops, range

How do I specify a maximum in the range function to that it reverts back to the beginning after a certain number?

i.e:

```
for i in range(253, 2):
    print i

Would print 253, 254, 255, 0 , 1, 2
```

If the maximum was 255

---

**Edit** (after reading comments and answers)

This should work right?

```
if start < end:
    list = [ i for i in range(start, end + 1 ) ]
else:
    list = [ i % 256 for i in range(start, end + 256 + 1 ) ]
```

Looking back at this, people seem to love complexity over simplicity. Why use itertools and other complicated constructs when it can be done with a simple loop?

Comment: You mean a loop that iterates from x to y and then resets back to x and keeps iterating? You probably don't want a `for` loop for that.

Comment: @AlexW: Actually, you do.  That's easily done with `itertools.cycle(range(...))` and the result is quite suitable for a `for` loop.

Comment: @Kevin [Behind the scenes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) that is just a `while` loop.

Comment: @AlexW: If I cared about "behind the scenes," I would be coding in C.

Comment: @alex it is very common python style to split out the bookkeeping logic and end up with something consumable by a `for` loop.

Comment: It's missing a `]` on the second list, you should lowercase your variables, and remove the space between `range` and `(`.

Comment: @lvc: To be fair, `itertools.cycle()` does consume an unnecessary amount of memory for large `range()` objects in 3.x (or `xrange()` in 2.x).  A simple while loop is more performant in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood well, it's not exactly a `range` issue.

Given 2 numbers `min` and `max`:

- if `min < max`, you want the list of numbers between  `min` and `max`
- else you want the list from `min` to `255` and `0` to `max`

It's only pseudo-code, but it might be enough to get you started to solve your problem (using one or two `range`calls)

Comment: I think this is what OP wants actually.

Comment: Yes, it seems fine to me (but you should use lowercase variables: `start` `end`, and maybe a `maximum` as well). Please set this answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use modular arithmetic (or clock arithmetic). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

If you want to print `253, 254, 255, 0, 1, ..., 252`, you can use the following code.

```
for i in range(0, 256):
    print((253+i)%256)
```

Comment: The range is passed to me I have no control over it and most of the time it's a normal range i.e: 80-90, 10-15 etc....But sometimes it's 252-10, etc...

I want to just be able to pass that range to the range function, but it doesn't work

Comment: Okay, so you get two integers, say `left` and `right`, so if `left` < `right`, the printing is straightforward, but what happens when `left` > `right` such as 252-10; how do you know if you have to go to 255 before moving to 0?

Comment: "If you want to print 253, 254, 255, 0, 1, ..., 252". Reading the question, it's not what he wants. He wants "253, 254, 255, 0 , 1, 2"

Answer (score 1):

There is some issues with the way you specify the range. But you could do something like this:

```
max_val = 255
for i in range(253, max_val+2):
    print i%max_val
```

But since `range` is specified with the end value not included you would need to do `range(253, (max_val+1)+2)` if you want the `2` to be printed.

If you beforehand do not know if the range-end value will be more or less than the range-start you could do

```
start = 253
end = 2 # +1 if you want the 2 to be printed
for i in range(start, end+(start>end and max_val or 0)):
    print i%max_val
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it into two ranges: `range1 = range(start, highest+1)` and `range2 = range(end)`. Then using itertools, you can:

```
for i in it.chain(range1, range2):
```